# PyMongo freezes when I call insert

Tags: pymongo

I'm trying to learn how to use PyMongo, so I borrowed some code from a tutorial. Here's the entire program:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

cars = [ {'name': 'Audi', 'price': 52642},
    {'name': 'Mercedes', 'price': 57127},
    {'name': 'Skoda', 'price': 9000},
    {'name': 'Volvo', 'price': 29000},
    {'name': 'Bentley', 'price': 350000},
    {'name': 'Citroen', 'price': 21000},
    {'name': 'Hummer', 'price': 41400},
    {'name': 'Volkswagen', 'price': 21600} ]


client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
print("Created client")
with client:
    db = client.testdb
    print("Created db") 
    db.cars.insert_many(cars)
    print("Inserted")
```

When I run it, it prints "Created client" and "Created db", but never prints "Inserted", and the program never terminates.

I'm using Python 3.8.5, the Eclipse IDE, and I just did "pip install PyMongo" today, so I should have the latest version. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Whoops, I didn't realize that you have to install MongoDB separately from PyMongo!